# Convert curl to httpGet

Tags: java, json, curl, http-get

I am looking to use the following curl request in a java code. I see that we can use httpget to call rest services.

Here is my curl command:

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search' -d '{"_source": {"include": [ "field1", "name1" ]}, "query" : {"term": { "Date" :"2000-12-23T10:12:05" }}}'
```

How can I put that command in my HttpGet `httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(....);`

Please advice. Thanks.

Comment: Examples are available here: http://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-httpclient-examples/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html).
*This code is an example I think it will work for you:*

```
public void get() throws IOException{
    //Create a URL object.
    String url = "localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search";
    URL getURL = new URL(url);

    //Establish a https connection with that URL.
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) getURL.openConnection();

    //Select the request method, in this case GET.
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());

    String parameters = "{\"_source\": {\"include\": [ \"field1\", \"name1\" ]}, \"query\" : {\"term\": { \"Date\" :\"2000-12-23T10:12:05\" }}}";

    //Write the parameter into the Output Stream, flush the data and then close the stream.
    wr.writeBytes(parameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    int responseCode;
    try {
        responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: Connection problem.");
    }

    //Read the POST response.
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    String inputLine;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        //Save a line of the response.
        response.append(inputLine + '\n');
    }
    br.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

**If that doesnt work it's because i must have misstyped the parameters, try it anyway**

Answer (score 0):

The combination [-X GET and -d](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) results in your data being appended to the URL in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format.

Therefore, I suggest using [URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) as follows:

```
String host = "localhost:9200/indexname/status/_search";
String data = "{\"_source\": {\"include\": [ \"field1\", \"name1\" ]}, \"query\" : {\"term\": { \"Date\" :\"2000-12-23T10:12:05\" }}}";
String url = host + "?" + URLEncoder.encode(data, "UTF-8");
```